# mount system call in linux cannot display the mountpoint of file system by df command

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, linux-disk-free

I am trying to use `mount()` instead of `mount` command in my program, I use the following `mount()` successfully, the result returned success instead of `Invalid Argument`.

```cpp
int rc = mount("172.16.74.20:/data/redun/snmp","/mnt/data/redun/snmp",
                    "nfs",0,"soft,timeo=2,addr=172.16.74.20");

if (rc != 0)
 {
     printf("mount failed, errCode=%d, reason=%s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
 }
```

But when I use `df -h` to check the mountpoint, there are nothing displayed.
I found the related device was not mounted yet. What happened? Is it really mounted successfully? How can I display the mounted device by `df` command in Linux?

Comment: Doesn't `df` read `/etc/mtab` which is updated by `mount` command, but not `mount()` syscall? Check you `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: Yes, I found the mountpoint info under /proc/mounts as well. but there is nothing displayed after running 'df -h'

Comment: So the problem is about `/etc/mtab`, not about mount namespaces. I've posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `mount()` syscall, unlike `mount` command, doesn't update `/etc/mtab` file, while `df` command parses `/etc/mtab` to list mount points.

However, uptodate list of mount points is always available in `/proc/mounts` file. Unlike `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/mounts` is not a regular file, but instead a virtual file provided by kernel.

---

On some distributions, `/etc/mtab` is a symlink to `/proc/mounts`. If it's not, and you want `df` to work, you can do the following:

```
cat /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab
```

*after* every `mount()` or `umount()` call.

You can also make `/etc/mtab` a symlink to `/proc/mounts` or better `/proc/self/mounts`, but do it on your own risk (maybe some applications depend on it, but maybe it's just a bug in your distro).

---

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/is-it-possible-to-tell-df-to-use-proc-mounts-instead-of-etc-mtab).