# How to pass options into the mount system call?

Tags: linux, system-calls, mount

I want to mount 100 MB tmpfs within a C program in Linux. 
How can pass pass mount's options (i.e. -o size=100M,mode=0755) to the *mount* syscall?

It is the mount interface for C:

```
#include <sys/mount.h>

int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
            const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
            const void *data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [mount(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) man-page, it seems that filesystem independent options are given in `mountflags` as combination of different flags, and other filesystem specific options in `data` as comma-separated string exactly as they are used in [mount(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

So in your case just pass those options as string:

```
const char *data = "size=100M,mode=0755";
...
mount(source, target, filesystemtype, mountflags, data);
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I sent file-system options via data, but i can't find my tmpfs. Can I use this partition outside of my program.

Comment: Look into this address:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814782/mount-system-call-in-linux-cannot-display-the-mountpoint-of-file-system-by-df-co